# read file in Quarkus Reactive

Tags: reactive-programming, quarkus, mutiny, quarkus-reactive

I am try to read a json file and get that json string in my quarkus application. I am using reactive pattern using Mutiny. How can I write this using reactive pattern in quarkus

```
InputStream inputStream = SqsConsumer.class.getResourceAsStream("/Spec.json");
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)
```

Comment: Why not read it when the application starts up in normal blocking fashion and then just use the parsed content  when you are serving requests?

Comment: I agree with @geoand. If you really need async, Vert.x has an asynchronous file system API (we do have the Mutiny API for that API)